# Why are there blank rows in csv reader list output?

Tags: python, csv

I have the following code:

```
import CSV
row = ['4', 'Charan', 'Pune']
with open('modify_existing.csv')as readFile:
    reader= csv.reader(readFile)
    lines = list(reader)
    lines[3] = row
with open('modify_existing.csv', 'w') as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
    writer.writerows(lines)
print(lines)
```

It's CSV file:

```
1, Bala, Pune
1, Harshini, Chennai
2, Adhith, Mumbai
4, Ron, Delhi
4, egiste, Tiruchy
5, Venkat, Madurai
```

After the execution, for my convineince, I printed the list lines. The output was:

```
[['1', 'Bala', 'Pune'], ['1', ' Harshini', ' Chennai'], ['2', ' Adhith', ' Mumbai'], ['4', 'Charan', 'Pune'], ['4', ' egiste', ' Tiruchy'], ['5', ' Venkat', ' Madurai']]
```

In the second time when I execute, I get:

```
[['1', 'Bala', 'Pune'], [], ['1', ' Harshini', ' Chennai'], ['4', 'Charan', 'Pune'], ['2', ' Adhith', ' Mumbai'], [], ['4', 'Charan', 'Pune'], [], ['4', ' egiste', ' Tiruchy'], [], ['5', ' Venkat', ' Madurai'], []]
```

Why do I get these blank lines in between? Next time, when I execute the same, I get more blank lines. I am using Windows and if I mention `newline=''` in open() or `lineterminator='\n'` in the writer(), I don't get these blank lines. I'm viewing my CSV file in notepad

Needed:

I don't need the solution to avoid these blank lines,
I just need to know why those blank lines appear.
If explained clearly with that mechanism, it will be helpful

Bounty on the way

Comment: My question is how did you get `['4', 'Charan', 'Pune']` twice if you only edit the same row each time?

Comment: @OneCricketeer It's because of the blank line. So the row he added became `lines[6]` the second time, then he replaced `lines[3]`.

Comment: I suspect the problem is due to the file having CR LF line endings when you wrote it, and Python is treating that as two newlines.

Comment: Try adding the keyword argument `newline=''` to _both_ `open()` calls (as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)).

Comment: @martineau 
Check my question. I didn't ask for solution.

Comment: If you try it and **if** it works (you can then look up what the argument does and this will tell you what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator) each line is terminated using `'\r\n'` by the csv writer. So if there is a new line character already present in list writer adds another one, so you will get extra new line.

Now let's check whether we had a new line character in list

```
import csv
row = ['4', 'Charan', 'Pune']
with open('data.csv')as readFile:
    reader= csv.reader(readFile)
    lines = list(reader)
    lines[3] = row
print(lines)
for line in lines:
    print(",".join(line))
```

is resulting

```
[['1', ' Bala', ' Pune'], ['1', ' Harshini', ' Chennai'], ['2', ' Adhith', ' Mumbai'], ['4', 'Charan', 'Pune'], ['4', ' egiste', ' Tiruchy'], ['5', ' Venkat', ' Madurai']]
1, Bala, Pune
1, Harshini, Chennai
2, Adhith, Mumbai
4,Charan,Pune
4, egiste, Tiruchy
5, Venkat, Madurai
```

If you observer, I haven't used newline character in printing lines, but still newline characters are printing in the result.

This clarifies one important point that csv reader is not discarding the newline character on it's own. Since reader is not discarding the new line character it is safe to discard newline by using `open(filename, newline='')`.

check [footnote](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#Footnotes) for reference

Answer (score 0):

I use your code for testing the diferent solutions and i found some ways.

1. The first one is that you use a diferent file to save the data, its the most normal solution because you have a new complety empty file.
2. If you want to use the same file, you have to specify some more parameters, and from what I see, use some good practices, such as colsing the files after use or specific the methot that you use to read/write files, read then documentation for more information.

Use the following code:

```
    import csv
    row = ['4', 'Charan', 'Pune']
    with open('modify_existing.csv', 'r+') as readFile:
        reader= csv.reader(readFile)
        lines = list(reader)
    print(lines)
    lines[3] = row
    with open('modify_existing.csv', 'w+', newline='') as writeFile:
        writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
        writer.writerows(lines)
    print(lines)
```

I hope I've helped!

Comment: when you open an file using `with` context, you don't need to close the file explicitly because the context manager implement the `close` method.

Comment: If true. I forgot that detail